# Replicating Matlab functionality on Spyder

Tags: python, matlab, spyder

In Matlab I frequently use two important functionalities:

- `cd` to folder and have it automatically update Matlab File explorer
- Save workspace with various file paths as string variables which I then use with `cd` command to jump from one path to the other with relative ease and view folder contents

Lately I have taken an interest in Python via Spyder IDE because I know Python kicks Matlab's butt on many levels. I have not, however been able to replicate the two functions above. Yes Spyder does have a File explorer accessible via the View>Panes>File Explorer menu but there seems not to be a programmatic way to manipulate the file explorer itself, or to save a workspace containing string variables.

How best to replicate these functionalities? If not what are some viable alternative functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) About the functionalities you use in Matlab:

1. Synchronizing `cd` with the File Explorer will be done in Spyder **3.2** (to be released in a month).
2. Passing variables to `cd` looks like an interesting idea, but it's not something we can solve in Spyder. You should open an issue about it in the [IPython issue tracker](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues).

Comment: in this case what python library would your recommend to control Matlab from Spyder? This kind of functionality is very important for me..

Comment: I found a popular one called pymat but cannot seem to find a way to install it on spyder

Comment: @user32882, your best chance is to report this in IPython, and even better, come up with a pull request for it. You won't get the kind of functionality you want by trying to interface Python with Matlab, sorry.